# sorting of an array alphabetically in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to sort my array alphabetically in objective-c. I have implemented it this way.

```
//Sorting of the Array
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrName sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Cars *firstObject, Cars *secondObject) {
    return [firstObject.str_name compare:secondObject.str_name];
}];
arrName =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
```

The problem is all the numbers appear followed by captial letters words followed by lowercase letters items...

I want it to appear alphabetically-> meaning to say that the capital letters and lowercase letters maybe mixed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace `compare:` with `caseInsensitiveCompare:`.

Since `arrName` is mutable, use the 'sortUsingComparator' method instead. It will sort the mutable array in place without creating a new array.

```
[arrName sortUsingComparator:^(Cars *firstObject, Cars *secondObject) {
    return [firstObject.str_name caseInsensitiveCompare:secondObject.str_name];
}];
```

Comment: then am i right to say that sortedArray has to become of type NSMutableArray?

Comment: No, you don't need `sortedArray`.

Comment: have i done it correctly?

Comment: Almost. See my update.

Comment: If anyone is using set of characters other than latin they should use comparator: `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Object1",@"object1", nil];      
array =[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Comment: This won't work. It's not an array of strings, it's an array of objects and the sort is on a property of the objects.